# I am getting deferred error : (error Keyword argument :triggered not one of (:requires :force-init)) on C-TAB

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-jedi

I'm pretty new to Emacs but I recently tried installing Jedi.el for Python Development.
The installation worked fine, I used marmalade.

But now, when I open a Python file and try to invoke the auto-completion using C-TAB I get this error.

```
deferred error : (error Keyword argument :triggered not one of (:requires :force-init))
```

While searching for this error I found this issue:
https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/133

But I have the current version of auto-complete installed.
According to `package-list-packages` version 1.4.0 is installed.

So I followed the troubleshooting steps.

Here is the output of `jedi:show-setup-info`:

```
    ;; Emacs Lisp version:
    (:emacs-version "24.3.1" :jedi-version "0.2.0alpha2" :python-environment-version                 "0.0.2alpha0")
    ;; Python version:
    ((:version "3.4.0 (default, Mar 17 2014, 23:20:09) \n[GCC 4.8.2 20140206         (prerelease)]" :file nil :name "sys")
    (:version "0.7.0" :file "/home/skoehnen/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jedi/__init__.py" :name "jedi")
    (:version "0.0.5" :file "/home/skoehnen/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python3.4/site-packages/epc/__init__.py" :name "epc")
    (:version "0.0.3" :file "/home/skoehnen/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sexpdata.py" :name "sexpdata"))
    ;; Command line:
    (:virtualenv "/usr/bin/virtualenv" :virtualenv-version "1.11.4\n")
    ;; Customization:
    ((jedi:complete-on-dot . t)
     (jedi:doc-display-buffer . display-buffer)
     (jedi:doc-hook view-mode)
     (jedi:doc-mode . rst-mode)
     (jedi:environment-root)
     (jedi:environment-virtualenv)
     (jedi:get-in-function-call-delay . 1000)
     (jedi:get-in-function-call-timeout . 3000)
     (jedi:goto-definition-config
      (nil nil nil)
      (t nil nil)
      (nil definition nil)
      (t definition nil)
      (nil nil t)
      (t nil t)
      (nil definition t)
      (t definition t))
     (jedi:goto-definition-marker-ring-length . 16)
     (jedi:imenu-create-index-function . jedi:create-nested-imenu-index)
     (jedi:import-python-el-settings . t)
     (jedi:install-imenu)
     (jedi:install-python-jedi-dev-command "pip" "install" "--upgrade"         "git+https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git@dev#egg=jedi")
     (jedi:key-complete .
                [C-tab])
     (jedi:key-goto-definition .
                   [67108910])
     (jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker .
                          [67108908])
     (jedi:key-related-names . "r")
     (jedi:key-show-doc . "d")
     (jedi:server-args)
     (jedi:server-command "/home/skoehnen/.emacs.d/.python-        environments/default/bin/jediepcserver")
     (jedi:setup-keys)
     (jedi:tooltip-method pos-tip popup)
     (jedi:use-shortcuts)
     (python-environment-default-root-name . "default")
     (python-environment-directory . "~/.emacs.d/.python-environments")
     (python-environment-virtualenv "virtualenv" "--system-site-packages" "--quiet"))
```

`M-: jedi-mode RET` returned `t`

And I added `(global-auto-complete-mode t)` to `.emacs`

Of course I also tried getting a traceback (it being a deferred error), after `jedi:toggle-log-traceback` I hit C-TAB a few times, but in the EPC buffer was only a number (I assume it is the port number?).

So now I don't know what else to check, maybe someone here can help me.